# Django formset edit not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to used dynamic form set in django. for that i have used django formset. it works perfectly. now i need to give edit option for this forms. so I need to show previously added data in my form set. for that i have written  following code. but it does not show previous
added data. only show empty form set even if it has data

```
if action == 'edit':
        teaching_module = TeachingModule.objects.get(id=
                                                  request.GET.get('id'))
        form = TeachingModuleForm(instance=teaching_module)

        teaching_module = TeachingModule.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
        factory = modelformset_factory(TeachingModuleSegment, form = TeachingModuleSegmentForm)
        qset = TeachingModuleSegment.objects.filter(teachingModule=teaching_module)
        formset = factory(queryset=qset)

        data = {'form': form,
                'formset': formset}

        return render(request, 'add_teaching_modules.html', data)
```

Comment: does this queryset select instaces You want to edit `qset = TeachingModuleSegment.objects.filter(teachingModule=teaching_module)`?

Comment: here i need to filter by foreignkey. it is only for get the previously added data. i need to edit TeachingModuleSegment data. that saving part not written here. this is only for display the previous data

Comment: why don't You use `inlineformset_factory` ?

Comment: can u give me sample example or tutorial link?

Comment: You variant seems to be correct tho

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand You want to edit all instances of model linked via foreign key
For this purposes there is InlineFormsets and `inlineformset_factory`

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key.

please try them instead